# AuthorizationFilterContext returns null on context.HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I have a RestrictedAttribute to protect my controllers that implments the `OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)` from the IAuthorizationFilter.

Then I need to check if the user is authenticated using following code:

```cs
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    IPrincipal user = context.HttpContext.User;
    
    // If the user is not authenticated...
    
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        TraceFailure("Unauthorized. User (principal identity) is not authenticated.", null);
    
        // Add to response HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
    }
}
```

All my controllers are inherited by our custom `ApiBaseController` that has the `[Restricted]` attribute like:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Defines the base class for all API controllers.
/// </summary>
[Restricted]
[DynamicClaims]
[CultureAware]
public abstract class ApiBaseController : ControllerBase
```

I send a valid token to the request but the `user` has all its parameters as null and the IsAuthenticated is always false (because is the default value).

I configured my Authentication and Authorization like following:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityClientMiddlewareService(
            this IServiceCollection services)
{
    try
    {
        services.AddAuthorization((options) =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
            "DefaultScope",
            (policy) =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string>
                {
                    "Bearer"
                };

                policy.RequireClaim("scope", Configuration.WebApiScopes);
            });
        }).AddAuthentication((options) => 
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Cookies;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Oidc;
        }).AddCookie(AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Cookies, (options) =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
            options.CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new ChunkingCookieManager());
        }).AddOpenIdConnect(AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Cookies, (options) =>
        {
            // Set the identity server endpoint

            options.Authority = Configuration.AuthorityEndpoint;

            // Set the authentication type

            // Set the grant used (hybrid)

            options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";

            // Set client id and client secret

            options.ClientId = Configuration.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration.ClientSecret;

            // Set the scopes requested

            options.Scope.Add(Configuration.WebUserInterfaceScopes);

            // Setup notifications from the middleware

            options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                // Notified when the authentication fails

                OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,

                // Notified when the security token is received

                OnTokenResponseReceived = OnTokenResponseReceivedAsync,

                // Notified when the security token has been validated

                OnTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidatedAsync,

                // Notified when an authorization code is received

                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync,

                // Notified when a redirect to an identity provider is requested

                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,

                // Notified when a protocol message is received

                OnMessageReceived = OnMessageReceivedAsync,
            };
        }).AddJwtBearer((options) =>
        {
            // Setup the bearer token authentication middleware
            // This middleware is for the Web API

            // Set the identity server endpoint

            options.Authority = Configuration.AuthorityEndpoint;
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound = true;

            // Token validation options
            // Disable audience validation

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            };
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to configure the Identity Server.", ex);
    }
        
    return services;
}
```

Why is my `context.HttpContext.User` is not populated with the metadata? I am missing something?

Comment: Does you specified the right authentication scheme on your endpoint ? As i saw the default authentication scheme you use was `AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Cookies`, so... If the endpoint was just guard by a simple `[Authorize]`, then ofcourse, it's null, regardless whichever Jwt token we sent.

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. All my controllers are derived from our custom ApiBaseController that has the [Restricted] attribute.

Comment: So... we need the implementation of `[Restricted]` as well. The point is `HttpContext.User` was the result of Authentication flow. If our `[Restricted]` attribute implementation have something do to with it(and also its handler if any), then we can trace that back, otherwise, the problem stay with Authentication Scheme problem as i mention above.

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. the implementation of `[Restricted]` is the first example code for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... After quite a few time came back to the maze... finnaly i spot something out.

The `AddAuthentication` config determine `AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Cookies` as its default authentication scheme(and I guess we forget to change the scheme on  `AddOpenIdConnect`, as it currently Cookie name). `DefaultChallengeScheme` was specified to `AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Oidc`, but if the request was not redirect, that prove it use cookie authentication to verify and passed down.

`a valid token` now has no use since we doesn't specify out what specific Authentication scheme on the endpoint. Therefore, it use the default cookie thing.

This was base on assumption that we're not drop `app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization();`.

I would bet change defaultAuthentication to the right one would solve the prob

```
.AddAuthentication((options) => 
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Oidc;
        })
```